# Rebalancing Ice Claw as a 7th level spell

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, balance

The *Ice Claw* spell from the Spell compendium is very weak for a 7th level spell.

It does a grapple but the damage is very weak for its level how would you go about balancing the spell to be more in line with 7th level power of spells.

Comment: Requests for homebrew content are generally off-topic for our site, unfortunately. But there's usually people in chat who might be willing to help you out if you want to tinker with a spell.

Comment: @Erik Not off-topic so much as too-broad. But this, I think, is reasonably scoped—a 7th-level spell makes a reasonably definitive balance point, and expanding in an existing spell gives us a fairly narrow idea of the kinds of things it should do. It seems like there should be little trouble for experts to vote on implementations.

Comment: This is an idea generation question, though; it's asking "how would you balance this to be better?" There's no right or wrong answer. As such, it's not really on-topic for RPG.SE.

Comment: @V2Blast I think it might actually be an X/Y problem. Asker, please, rephrase the question: *Is the spell* ice claw *weak for its level?* Then folks that want to take the extra step of rebalancing the spell can do that after answering the question.

Comment: (It's also nice to give folks a heads-up if [the question's been crossposted elsewhere](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?558582-Ice-Claw-spell-is-weak-ways-to-make-it-better).)